# execute method with task scheduler wrapper library

Tags: c#

i have a simple job class and i want to execute it continuously.I've done little search and i found `Microsoft.Win32.Task-scheduler` library. but i can't found out how to execute one my class method with it.

I'm new in C# programing so accept my apologies if it is a silly question. and if there is better way in order to develops a task scheduler application i really apprenticed to let me know.

this is my job class:

```
class Job
{
    private int counter = 0;
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name;
    }
    public override void DoJob()
    {
        //do a job
        counter++;
    }
    public override bool IsRepeatable()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override int GetRepetitionIntervalTime()
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using  [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) for this kind of work:

It works similarly to your code, and you can create multiple job classes that implement the `IJob` interface.